# Algolia, only match words with 2 or more characters matching?

Tags: php, algolia

Is there a way to make words only show as matched words if 2 or more characters match?

An example is:

```
'_highlightResult' => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => 
        array (size=3)
          'value' => string 'Dale Farm <em>Butter</em> Portions 100'<em>s</em>' (length=49)
```

You can see that "s" is matching from the query, though that's a bit daft as it isn't really something I'd want to match on.

Scanning through the docs still, in case I spot something.

Comment: Setting remove stop words to on, in the index settings seems to stop this, though it would be nice just to have a min length to match on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `minLength` is not really compatible with the native prefix & as-you-type search of Algolia.

That being said if you don't implement "as-you-type" search the `removeStopWords` index settings is indeed probably the good way to go!

Comment: Thanks, in this particular search it's for out of stock alternatives so as you type isn't needed.